# What is the perfect closure of $ \Bbb{F}_p((t))$ and its value group?

Tags: field-theory, galois-theory, algebraic-number-theory

What is the perfect closure of $ \Bbb{F}_p((t))$ and its value group ?
I think perfect closure is $ \Bbb{F}_p((t^{1/p^∞}))$, and I think  if so, $\bigcup_{n\geqq1}(1/p^n) \Bbb{Z}$?

$ \Bbb{F}_p((t^{1/p^∞}))$ is certainly perfect, but I don't have an idea how to prove this is an perfect **closure** of $ \Bbb{F}_p((t))$.

Comment: $\Bbb{F}_q((t^{1/q}))$ is not perfect. Any guess on what is $\Bbb{F}_q((t^{1/q}))^q$ ?

Comment: Seems like the value group of $\Bbb F_q((t^{1/q}))$ is $\frac{1}{q}\Bbb Z$, not $\bigcup \frac{1}{p^n}\Bbb Z$.

Comment: You edited the question to replace $\Bbb F_q((t^{1/q}))$ with $\Bbb F_q((t^{1/q}))^q$... but isn't $\Bbb F_q((t^{1/q}))^q$ just $\Bbb F_q((t))$ itself?

Comment: Your $\zeta_{p^\infty}$ is meaningless: in fields of characteristic $p$ there are no $p$-power roots of unity besides $1$.

Comment: The notation $\Bbb{F}_p((t^{1/p^\infty}))$ is a bit ambiguous, for example $\sum_{n\ge 0} t^{n+1/p^n}$ isn't in the perfect closure of $\Bbb{F}_p((t))$. The perfect closure of $k$ is $\bigcup_{n\ge 1} k^{1/p^n}$ and $\Bbb{F}_p((t))^{1/p^n}=\Bbb{F}_p((t^{1/p^n}))$.